# unable to see output image in R shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny, output

i'm trying to show a logo in my Shiny app, but when i try to see i only can see a small icon, but not the image, this is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  mainPanel(
    img(src='C:/Users/carlo239/image[![enter image description here][1]][1]/Capture2.jpg', 
        align = "right", height = '300px'),
    ### the rest of your code
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And this is the issue, i tried to reload, but is not working,
I know that the image is ok, because if i click on Download i get the same image, but i'm unable to see in my outputs. THANKS !!

[image]

Comment: put the image in the `www` folder and just point to name  `img(src = 'Capture2.jpg',...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Put the file in the www folder of your app (as suggested by @YBS). That is in most cases the recommended solution.
2. "Register" your folder as resource folder for your app (see below). However, that solution is intended to help package authors make resources available to the package's  components. Also be aware that absolute paths can pose problems when you deploy your app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    img(src='/foo/Capture2.jpg', 
        align = "right", height = '300px'),
    ### the rest of your code
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  addResourcePath("foo", "C:/Users/wherever/your/file/may/be/located")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```